# Как добавить маркер выбора собственного местоположения, как в приложениях такси

Tags: java, android, yandexmapkit

Всем привет! Как реализовать подобный маркер выбора местоположения, при этом используя yandexMapKit.  [image: пример работы]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того чтобы метка все время оставалась в центре экрана, нужно подписаться на [CameraCallback](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/mapkit/doc/android-ref/lite/com/yandex/mapkit/map/Map.CameraCallback.html?lang=ru) и при каждом вызове [onMoveFinished](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/mapkit/doc/android-ref/lite/com/yandex/mapkit/map/Map.CameraCallback.html?lang=ru#_4) перемещать метку в центр [map.visibleRegion](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/mapkit/doc/android-ref/full/com/yandex/mapkit/map/VisibleRegion.html?lang=ru).

Либо (похоже, что тут привязка к карте не требуется) можно, просто, поверх карты нарисовать любую **view** средствами платформы. А брать координаты центра и геокодировать их при необходимости можно стандартными методами API.

Comment: Второй способ выглядит привлекательно и достаточно просто.